# sharepoint: how to register eventhandlers on creation of column from Site column

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-2010, event-handling, site-column, customcolumn

I am creating a custom column type in SharePoint. This custom column requires some event handlers (like itemAdding etc.) to be registered with the list which is using this column. Now user can also create a site column of this custom column type. 
Now if user creates new column in a list using this site column, is there a way to register event handlers on that list??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there are functions like OnAdded() OnUpdated() of SPField class which will be called just after addition/updation of a field.